# Ошибка "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported" после отправки post запроса

Tags: python, html, requests, post

Пробовал использовать этот код:

```
import requests

r = requests.post("https://job.сайт.ru/auth/self-employed/login", {"phone":"+12345678910"})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

но выходит ошибка:

```
{"systemMessage":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","message":"Упс! Что-то пошло не так...","errors":{}}
```

Как можно это исправить? Как я понял он ругается о том что кодировка UTF-8 не поддерживается, но к сожалению я не знаю как это исправить

```
:authority:job.сайт.ru
:method:POST
:path:/auth/self-employed/login
:scheme:https
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ru,en;q=0.9,ko;q=0.8
```

это если пользоваться сайтом и сделать этот же запрос через кнопки на сайте

Comment: Параметры у вас как должны передаться, в url, в теле в виде json или как?

Comment: Вы сейчас данные передаете через второй параметр, это параметр data, если туда словарь передавать - это будет считаться form urlencoded, как если бы запрос передавался из html формы, тип контента - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, а не json, например. На это и ругается сервер, а не на кодировку.

Comment: сайт не мой, параметры взяты их меню разработчика на сате.На сайт зайти не сможете он привязан к определенной сети

Comment: Коротко - пробуйте передавать данные через параметр json: `r = requests.post("https://job.сайт.ru/auth/self-employed/login", json={"phone":"+12345678910"})`

Comment: Спасибо, да ошибка была в этом,если хотите можете создать ответ

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr.** Нужно передать данные через параметр json, а не просто вторым параметром:

```
r = requests.post(url, json={"phone":"+12345678910"})
```

---

Ошибка не в кодировке, а в ContentType в целом: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - это тип контента, который отправляется из html форм, данные при этом передаются в теле запроса, но не в виде json, а одной строкой парами ключ=значение (вида `field1=value1&field2=value2`, см. [пример](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example)). Сервер вам отвечает, что такой тип запроса не поддерживается.

Скорее всего вам нужно передавать данные как json, а не в формате `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Тип контента `x-www-form-urlencoded` стал из-за того, что вы передали словарь просто вторым параметром без указания имени параметра, и он попал в параметр `data`. Библиотека `requests` при получении словаря или списка кортежей в этом параметре считает, что вы пытаетесь передать данные в виде `x-www-form-urlencoded`. См. [документацию](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Т.е. такой запрос:

```
r = requests.post(url, {"phone":"+12345678910"})
```

это то же самое что

```
r = requests.post(url, data={"phone":"+12345678910"})
```

и в итоге то же самое что

```
r = requests.post(url, data="phone=%2B12345678910")
```

Плюс превратился в `%2B` в результате url-кодирования (см. [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_URL)).

Как посмотреть фактическое тело запроса:

```
from requests import Request

request = Request("POST", url="https://job.сайт.ru/auth/self-employed/login", data={"phone":"+12345678910"}).prepare()
print(request.body)
```

Вывод

```
phone=%2B12345678910
```

---

Чтобы преобразовать словарь в json и передать его в теле запроса, нужно использовать параметр json:

```
r = requests.post(url, json={"phone":"+12345678910"})
```

либо передать уже сконвертированный в строку (сериализованный) json в параметр data, тогда это строка будет передана в теле запроса как есть:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps({"phone":"+12345678910"}))
```

Ну и итоговое тело запроса можно проверить:

```
from requests import Request

request = Request("POST", url="https://job.сайт.ru/auth/self-employed/login", json={"phone":"+12345678910"}).prepare()
print(request.body)
```

Вывод:

```
b'{"phone": "+12345678910"}'
```

b и одинарные кавычки просто обозначают что передаются бинарные данные, в самом теле запроса они не передаются.